# mouseover timeout too fast

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to set my mouseover at the left nav. But the problem is, the timeout is faster than it should be. How do I make it longer on mouseover?

```
stuHover = function () {
    var cssRule;
    var newSelector;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; x++) {
            cssRule = document.styleSheets[i].rules[x];
            if (cssRule.selectorText.indexOf("LI:hover") != -1) {
                newSelector = cssRule.selectorText.replace(/LI:hover/gi, "LI.iehover");
            document.styleSheets[i].addRule(newSelector, cssRule.style.cssText);
            }
        }
    }
    var getElm = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i = 0; i < getElm.length; i++) {
        getElm[i].onmouseover = function () {
            this.className += " iehover";
        }
        getElm[i].onmouseout = function () {
            this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp("iehover\\\b"), "")
            }
        }
    }
    if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", stuHover);
```

Comment: What exactly do you think is `\5000` doing to do? There is no timer code in your question's code at all!

Comment: ohh i'm sorry. i've altered the code. i'll edit it but can you alter the code to make it long last longer on mouseover?

Comment: I think you need to understand some basics - looking at your changed code you do lack basic knowledge about the language JavaScript which will make it hard for you to work with it..

Comment: @ace StackOverflow is not for "make this for me" questions. If you wish to learn JavaScript check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: okay so so what should i do then? could you help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
getElm[i].onmouseout = function() {
    var t = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        t.className = t.className.replace(" iehover","");
    },5000); // 5 seconds
};
```

Although really, if I had to wait 5 seconds for something to disappear if I accidentally moved over the trigger area, I'd be annoyed. Try `250` instead (0.25 seconds).

Comment: Note also that if you mouse back over the trigger area and leave the mouse there before the five seconds (or 250ms) is up, the timeout will still run and remove the class.

Comment: This doesn't handle clearing the timeout when hovered over once again; which will be his next post if you give him code that he thinks he can copy/paste and magically have work.

Comment: We do this (on our pure CSS menus, enhanced by javascript to delay instant CSS closing) but we also get any click outside the menu to immediately close it. That way, you can click on the page background if you accidentally activate the menu so you don't have to wait the 250ms.